# SectionIndex too far to the right

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

How do I move my sectionindex titles to the left 10 pixels? I tried by moving the scrollIndicatorInsets but that did't work.Also I don't want to move the tableview to the left since I need my section header to go all of way to the right.

[image]

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with a table view added? If the latter, make sure the table view's frame is correct.

Comment: it is a tableviewcontroller and I checked the frame